# Click event on element that doesn't exist on page load

Tags: jquery

I have the following jQuery in the body of my page. Basically, when a user clicks on the subscribe button, the button is replaced by a form with a text input and a submit button. So the form does not exist on page load.

By default the text input has "Enter your email" in it. I would like to empty the text field when the user clicks on it. I know how to do this if the form already exists when the page finished loading, but this is not the case here. I know I need to use a delegated event so I looked it up and came up with what you see in the second part of the script, however it's not working.

```
<script>
    $('#subscribeline #subscribe').click(function(){
        $('#subscribeline').html("<form id='subscribeform'><input type='email' name='email' id='email' value='Enter your email'><input type='submit' name='submit' id='submit' value='OK'></form>");
    });

    $( '#subscribeform #email' ).on( "click", "td", function() {
      $('#subscribeform #email').text('');
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Why don't use html5 placeholder instead as in <input placeholder='Enter your email'> ?

Comment: @webkit Thanks! Didn't even know that existed, don't do web scripting very often. This is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: :) sure, you have an example in the answer below..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are writing event wrong,write delegated event with `ul#subscribline` and on input whose id is email.

do like this:

```
 $( "#subscribeline" ).on( "click", "#email", function() {
      $(this).text("");
    });
```

and instead of writing text, you can use [placeholder](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_input_placeholder) property of html5.

See [**Example HERE**](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_input_placeholder)

you can add placeholder like this:

```
$('#subscribeline #subscribe').click(function(){
        $('#subscribeline').html("<form id='subscribeform'><input type='email' name='email' id='email' placeholder='Enter your email'><input type='submit' name='submit' id='submit' value='OK'></form>");
    });
```

and then you don't need to write click events and remove default text which is inside input field.